# Randomly generate sample while including all values at least one time in the random sample within R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to develop a sampling strategy using R such that I am randomly generating a sequence of values that includes every site within the final random sample.

My data looks like this:
`df<-data.frame(sites=1:30)`

And I am trying to generate 40 random values that includes every site (1-30) at least one time. I run the code:

```
sample(df$site,40,T)
 [1]  5 29  3 30  6 11 30 11  6 20 26 26  2 23 15 27  2 23  3 20 20 26  6 10 28 21
[27] 10  9  9  5 10 16 17 29 12 28 21 15  9 13
```

But everytime I run it, not I don't have all of my values. For example, in that random draw I have no site 1 in the sample. Is there a way to do this in tidyverse such that I generate 40 random values while including each site at least one time?

Comment: Exactly what type of distribution do you want?  If you require one from each site, it's not really "random". You could choose the numbers 1-30 and then "randomly" choose 10 additional values. For example: `sample(c(df$sites, sample(df$sites, 10))`. Depends on whether or not you want to allow duplicates in that additional sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
> set.seed(0)

> sites <- 1:30

> (out <- sample(c(sites, sample(sites, 40 - length(sites)))))
 [1]  4 21 30 10  7  9 15 11  5  1 25 14 25 28  2 23 12  7  1 20  3  6 30 18 19
[26] 23  4 24 29 17 14  2 16 22 13 11 18 26  8 27
```

and you can see the counts using `table`

```
> table(out)
out
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 2  2  1  2  1  1  2  1  1  1  2  1  1  2  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  1
27 28 29 30
 1  1  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw, there is no randomization at this.
So, similar to ThomasIsCoding, you can try:

```
df <- 1:30

newdf <- c(df, sample(df,10,T))
newdf

table(newdf)
```